# IntelliSense and Folding Editor Not Working in Visual Studio 2008 SP1 for Certain Files Only

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml, intellisense

Ok, I have an issue that is driving me nuts. In certain xaml files only, neither IntelliSense nor the folding editor is working.

I have noticed that if I delete the local namespace and add it back, the folding editor starts working.

If I delete the local namespace and don't add it back, IntelliSense starts working as well. Of course, I need to remember to add that namespace declaration back before I compile and/or check in ... which is annoying.

How can you fix this?

Comment: This most likely is *not* the solution, but when in doubt and having problems with VS, you can always close VS, delete the solution.suo file, and restart VS.  You lose things like breakpoints, but it does "clean up" the VS experience in many cases.

Comment: Thanks Wonko ... I actually already figured it out. I just wanted to spread the word. The first thing I try is the trick you mentioned. :)

Comment: Glad you found a solution.  The "suo" trick was my attempt at spreading the word too.  It's one of those "well, I don't think it will help, but I'll try it....dang, it *did* work!" things.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an internet [search](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=intellisense+xaml+not+working+local+namespace) brought me to this [post](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/3384), I figured it out. My problem wasn't exactly the same, but I discovered that **adding ';assembly=' to the local namespace declaration** solved my problem!

So, this xaml doesn't work:

```
<my:Inspector
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Snoop"
    x:Class="Snoop.PropertyGrid2"
    x:Name="PropertyGrid"
    MinHeight="0"
    MinWidth="0"
>
```

While this xaml **DOES** work:

```
<my:Inspector
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Snoop;assembly="
    x:Class="Snoop.PropertyGrid2"
    x:Name="PropertyGrid"
    MinHeight="0"
    MinWidth="0"
>
```

Hope this helps someone. I know it was ticking me off!

p.s. Seems only an issue with Visual Studio 2008. Visual Studio 2010 works fine in both cases above.

Comment: @user500099 Another thing that I have noticed ... in later versions of Visual Studio (especially VS2010) ... is that you can get the folding editor working again by temporarily deleting all the attributes on the root element and then waiting till the folding editor functionality comes back ... and then un-deleting those attributes.